# Pattern in ggpattern doesn't follow polygon borders after update

Tags: ggplot2, r-sf

I made some maps with spatial features from the sf package and used **ggpattern** to create a striped fill. This worked well for certain polygons, but not for those with holes in it (islands in a lake feature class).

Recently the ggpattern package has been updated to work with polygons with holes (for which I am grateful!), and it no longer gives errors for these features but now the pattern fill is wrong for all features (with and without holes), since it no longer follows the polygon borders but instead fills a rectangle around the polygons.

Here's an example using the rnaturalearth package to show what I mean.

```
#devtools::install_github("coolbutuseless/ggpattern")
library(ggpattern)
library(rnaturalearth)

germany <- ne_countries(country='germany', returnclass='sf')
ggplot() + geom_sf_pattern(data = germany)
```

This gives me this as a result.

[image: this]

And here are pictures of my actual map [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVngr.png) and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/852Nj.png) the ggpattern update for polygons without holes, using unchanged code and data.

I've looked through the ggpattern page to see if I am missing certain parameters that I need to change, but can't seem to find the issue. I am relatively new to R so maybe I overlooked something. Would appreciate any help to point me in the right direction!

Comment: Hello @Amber. Don't know what the problem is. When I run your code, the pattern is enclosed within the polygon (i.e. Germany's borders)

Comment: Confirm - running fine on my machine (see output https://i.imgur.com/ArA18Mo.png) - was a good opportunity to update all my packages - have you done so too? Especially ggplot2 and sf?

Comment: Hi, thank you both for your answers! Unfortunately I keep having the issue after updating the packages. I suppose there must be some settings somewhere that I would need to change, but it's good to know that it's definitely an issue on my end and not with the package. If anyone has an idea of where to look for the issue, all help is welcome.

Comment: For anyone who is interested in this issue: it seems that the updated ggpattern package uses new R features that are not supported by my Windows graphic device. So it seems that for now the only solution for me is to run the code using the new ggpattern on a different OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your `{ggpattern}` and `{gridpattern}` packages to the latest (development) versions using `remotes::install_github(coolbutuseless/ggpattern)`.  There were some issues with `geom_sf_pattern()` pattern clipping/masking which were fixed last week (Jan. 16th-20th, 2022).  Theoretically it should work now.  You shouldn't need to use a different OS.

If it still doesn't work some workarounds to try:

1. Explicitly turn off (or on) R 4.1 features with `options(ggpattern_use_R4.1_features = FALSE)`.  Normally this shouldn't explicitly be needed since `{gridpattern}` can guess R 4.1 support in the active graphics device...
2. Save images using a different graphics device such as `pdf()` or `ragg::agg_png()` instead of the default interactive windows device.  Use a pdf/png viewer that automatically refreshes when image file is over-written.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works for me now but only when I save as pdf. But since that works my issue is solved in any case.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue. If you go on Github it's bug already reported. However, the solution proposed doesn't work for me. So I propose you an alternative solution.

```
devtools::install_github("statnmap/HatchedPolygons")
require(HatchedPolygons)
require(rnaturalearth)
    
ger <- st_as_sf(germany)

hatch <- hatched.SpatialPolygons(ger, density = 4, angle = 45)
hatch <- hatch %>% sf::st_set_crs(st_crs(germany))

ggplot(germany) + 
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(data = hatch)
```

[image]

If you want specific hatched regions, you should first create the hatched polygon desired and then clip it to your data and finally you plot it as sf object.

Comment: Thanks for this alternative solution!